# MySQLdb return `Decimal` for a `sum` of `INT`

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-python, temp-tables

This is the table definition I use to reproduce the issue:

```
create table test_sum_type 
(
  kind char(1) not null,
  n tinyint not null
);
```

Test data:

```
+------+---+                                                                                                                                                                                                    
| kind | n |                                                                                                                                                                                                    
+------+---+                                                                                                                                                                                                    
| A    | 1 |                                                                                                                                                                                                    
| B    | 1 |                                                                                                                                                                                                    
| A    | 2 |                                                                                                                                                                                                    
+------+---+
```

Query using `MySQLdb`:

```
In [32]: cur.execute("select kind, sum(n) from test_sum_type group by kind")                                                                                                                                    
Out[32]: 2L                                                                                                                                                                                                     

In [33]: cur.fetchall()                                                                                                                                                                                         
Out[33]: (('A', Decimal('3')), ('B', Decimal('1')))                                                                                                                                                             

In [34]: cur.execute("select kind, n from test_sum_type")                                                                                                                                                       
Out[34]: 3L                                                                                                                                                                                                     

In [35]: cur.fetchall()                                                                                                                                                                                         
Out[35]: (('A', 1), ('B', 1), ('A', 2))
```

As you can see, the resulting column is a `Decimal` when I use `sum`.

I've looked into the source code of [MySQLdb](https://github.com/farcepest/MySQLdb1/blob/master/MySQLdb/converters.py), there're only two field types set up to be converted to `Decimal` by default: `DECIMAL` and `NEWDECIMAL`.

What may be the reason of this? Is there any way to check the schema of some temporary table used in a specific query?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's by design in MySql.

> **[GROUP BY (Aggregate)
>   Functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html)**
>   **The SUM() and AVG() functions return a DECIMAL value** for exact-value
>   arguments (integer or DECIMAL), and a DOUBLE value for
>   approximate-value arguments (FLOAT or DOUBLE). (Before MySQL 5.0.3,
>   SUM() and AVG() return DOUBLE for all numeric arguments.)

If you need to return an `INT` then `CAST` it.

```
SELECT kind, CAST(SUM(n) AS SIGNED) n 
  FROM table1 
 GROUP BY kind
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/cf6df/1)** demo